# Given a prob measure P and a P-UI martingale $\{ \rho_t \}$ define $Q \sim P$ s.t. $E[\frac{dQ}{dP}|\mathscr{F}_t]=\rho_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

I know that if we have a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F},\{ \mathscr{F}_t \},P)$ and we have a probability measure Q equivalent to P, then there exists the Radon-Nikodym $\frac{dQ}{dP}:= \rho$ and we can define a UI martingale via $\rho_t:=E[\rho|\mathscr{F}_t].$ I would like to prove some type of converse result. If I'm given a probability measure $P$ and a UI martingale $\{ \rho_t \},$ how can I define a prob measure Q equivalent to P such that $\rho_t=E[\frac{dQ}{dP}|\mathscr{F}_t]$ (or prove that there exists such a Q)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, note that we need to assume that $\varrho_t \geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(\varrho_t)=1$ for all $t \geq 0$ (because otherwise $\varrho_t$ cannot be a conditional density of a probability measure).

Since $(\varrho_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale, it follows from the martingale convergence theorem that the limit $\varrho_{\infty} := \lim_{t \to \infty} \varrho_t$ exists in $L^1$ and almost surely. In particular, $\varrho_{\infty} \geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(\varrho_{\infty}) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(\varrho_t)=1$. This means that

$$\mathbb{Q}(A) := \int_A \varrho_{\infty} \, d\mathbb{P}$$

defines a probability measure. Moreover, $(\varrho_t)_{t \in [0,\infty]}$ is a martingale and so $$\mathbb{E} \left( \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}} \mid \mathcal{F}_t \right) = \mathbb{E}(\varrho_{\infty} \mid \mathcal{F}_t) = \varrho_t.$$

**Remark:** The assumption $\mathbb{E}(\varrho_t)=1$ is not very restrictive. Let $(\varrho_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a non-negative, uniformly integrable martingale. If $\mathbb{E}(\varrho_t)=0$, then $\varrho_t=0$ and so $\mathbb{Q}:=0$ satisfies $\mathbb{E}(d\mathbb{Q}/d\mathbb{P} \mid \mathcal{F}_t)=\varrho_t$. On the other hand, if $\mathbb{E}(\varrho_t)=\mathbb{E}(\varrho_0)$ is strictly positive (note that the expectation does not depend on $t$ because of the martingale property), then we can apply the above reasoning to the rescaled process $\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(\varrho_0)} \varrho_t$.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now. One more question related with this that it should be straigthforward but I can't see it. Assume we have a square-integrable martingale M. Define $T:= \inf \{t>0 : |M_t|>\frac{1}{2} \}.$ Then I can define prob measures $Q$ and $R$ such that $E[\frac{dQ}{dP}|\mathscr{F}_t]=1-N^T$ and $E[\frac{dR}{dP}|\mathscr{F}_t]=1+N^T.$ Why is $P= \frac{1}{2}Q + \frac{1}{2}R$?

Comment: It should be $1-M^T_t$ and $1+M^T_t.$

Comment: shouldn't it be $1-M_t^T$ and $1+M_t^T$? If not, what is N?

Comment: @Gono: yes yes, I was editing it... Do you know the answer?

Comment: First of all you need some additional assumptions, e.g. it has to hold $1-M_t^T \ge 0$ and $1+M_t^T \ge 0$ for all $t$. Then it follows for all $t\ge 0$ that $$E[\frac{1}{2}\frac{dQ}{dP} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{dR}{dP}|\mathcal{F}_t] = \frac{1}{2}(1 - M_t^T + 1 + M_t^T) = 1$$ so we get $$P = \frac{1}{2}Q + \frac{1}{2}R$$ on $$\mathcal{F}_\infty = \sigma\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_n\right)$$

Comment: Sorry, I can't see why $E[\frac{1}{2}\frac{dQ}{dP}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{dR}{dP}|\mathscr{F}_t] = 1$ implies $P= \frac{1}{2}Q+\frac{1}{2}R.$

Comment: With the above we have that for each $A \in \mathcal{F}_t$ it holds $$\begin{align} P(A) = E[1_A] &= E\left[E\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{dQ}{dP} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{dR}{dP}\right)1_A|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\right]\\&= E\left[\frac{1}{2}\frac{dQ}{dP}1_A + \frac{1}{2}\frac{dR}{dP}1_A\right] \\ &= \frac{1}{2}Q(A) + \frac{1}{2}R(A)\end{align}$$ So the statement holds for each $A \in \mathcal{F}_t$ and it follows that $P = \frac{1}{2}Q + \frac{1}{2}R$ holds on $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_n$. And because it's a Pi-System and a generator of $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ it holds there as well.

Comment: @Gono: Thank you very much,  your explanation is very clear.

Comment: @saz: In your answer, the probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ defined via $\mathbb{Q}(A) := \int_A \varrho_{\infty} \, d\mathbb{P}$ is a prob measure on $\mathscr{F}_{\infty}.$ But it's not necessarily a prob measure on $\mathscr{F},$ right?

Comment: @UBM Why do you think so? If $\mathbb{P}$ "lives" on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, then $\mathbb{Q}$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. More generally, if $\mu$ is some measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, then $$\nu(A) := \int_A f \, d\mu$$ defines a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ for every non-negative function $f \in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$

Comment: @saz: But $\varrho_{\infty}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of Q with respect to P on $\mathscr{F}_{\infty},$ so I assumed that you were taking $A$ from $\mathscr{F}_{\infty}.$ Is that correct?

Comment: @UBM You can define $\mathbb{Q}(A)$ for any $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and not only for $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\infty}$.

Comment: @saz: $\varrho_{\infty}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathscr{F}_{\infty},$ not on $\mathscr{F}$. I know I can define a probability measure $Q$ on $\mathscr{F}$ via $\mathbb{Q}(A) := \int_A \varrho_{\infty} \, d\mathbb{P},$ but that's not the point. The point of my original question is that $\mathbb{Q}$ **has to be is equivalent to** $\mathbb{Q}$ on the sigma-algebra.

Comment: @saz:I'm not questioning your great answer to my original question, I just want to clarify that with your proof we found a Q equivalent to P, but only on $\mathscr{F}_{\infty},$ not on $\mathscr{F}.$ Is this correct?

Comment: @saz: In case the answer to my previous question is "yes", is there any way to make Q equivalent to P on the bigger $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{F}$? If you think there is an answer to this question, please let me know and I'll post a new question.

Comment: @UBM Fact 1: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Fact 2: $\mathbb{Q}$ has a density with respect to $\mathbb{P}$, and hence $\mathbb{Q} \ll \mathbb{P}$ (both considered as measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$). I'm claiming not more than these two things. Do you think that they are wrong or do I just misunderstand what you are asking? Note that equivalence of probability measures would mean $\mathbb{P} \ll \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \ll \mathbb{P}$ but we cannot expect this unless $\varrho_{\infty}$ is strictly positive (which need, in general, not beed the case).

Comment: @saz: I agree with fact 1. Not  fully sure about  2. My original question was: "If I'm given a probability measure $P$ and a UI martingale $\{ \rho_t \},$ how can I define a prob measure Q **equivalent to** P such that $\rho_t=E[\frac{dQ}{dP}|\mathscr{F}_t]$?". I think your proof doesn't provide a Q equivalent to P.  As you said in your last comment, we know it is $Q \ll P$ but it may not be $P \ll Q.$ But it has a very easy solution, we can just start your proof by saying: "we need to assume that $\varrho_t > 0$ a.s. for every $t$”. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: But  even if we assume that the UI martingale is strictly positive, by following the steps in your proof, we will obtain a probability measure $Q$ equivalent to $P$ on $\mathscr{F}_{\infty},$ but not on $\mathscr{F}.$ Is this correct or you think $Q$ is also equivalent to $P$ on $\mathscr{F}$?  (My original question was vague I didn’t specify the sigma-algebra with respect to Q and P should be equivalents).

Comment: To give you the background: All this is because I’ve seen in a book a proof very similar to yours and they say that it’s not possible to find a Q equivalent to P on $\mathscr{F}.$ And then they state a Theorem  where they specifically say that the probability measure Q that obtain is equivalent to P with respect to $\mathscr{F}_{\infty},$ but not with respect to $\mathscr{F}.$ But I don’t understand why.  They just say that the problem is that $\mathscr{F}$ can be richer than $\mathscr{F}_{\infty}.$

Comment: I think your point is that both assumptions: $\rho$ strictly positive a.s. and $E[\rho_{\infty}]=1$ don't depend on the $\sigma$-algebra, so we can define Q for every $A \in \mathscr{F},$ and then we will have $\rho_{\infty} = \left. \frac{dQ}{dP} \right.|_{\mathscr{F}}.$ Correct?

Comment: @saz: I've just posted a new question using your previous comments.

Comment: @saz: I thought that maybe both, you and the book, were right and it was my understanding of the book what was wrong, so I copied the whole theorem from the book in the new question.

Comment: @saz: I've just posted a possible answer that goes against 'Fact 1': https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3484423/is-it-possible-to-obtain-the-radon-nikodym-derivative-left-fracdqdp-rig .I think that (in your proof) if we define $$\mathbb{Q}(A) := \int_A \varrho_{\infty} \, d\mathbb{P} \text{ for all } A \in \mathscr{F},$$ then we wouldn't have $E[\varrho_{\infty} | \mathscr{F}_t] = \varrho_t.$

Comment: @UBM I will take a look at it after christmas, sorry, I don't have the time now.

Comment: @saz: Ok, thank you.

Comment: @saz: Hi, if you have time could you please have a look at my answer in this question (It is also my own question) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527248/a-case-where-a-stochastic-exponential-is-a-true-martingale? I'm not sure if my answer is correct...