# Is it possible to obtain the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\left. \frac{dQ}{dP} \right|_{\mathscr{F}}$ from a UI martigale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

I have the following theorem:

**Theorem.**
Let P be a probability measure on $(\Omega, \{ \mathscr{F} \}, \mathscr{F}).$ Given an a.s. strictly positive UI $(\{ \mathscr{F} \},P)$-martingale $\rho$ with $E_P[\rho_{\infty}]=1$,
$$ \left. \frac{dQ}{dP} \right|_{\mathscr{F}_{\infty}}:= \rho_{\infty}$$
defines via 
$$Q(A) = \int_A \rho_{\infty} dP \quad \text{for every } A \in \mathscr{F}_{\infty}$$
a measure Q equivalent to P with respect to $\mathscr{F}_{\infty}.$

**Remark.** Note that if $\mathscr{F}$ is richer than $\mathscr{F}_{\infty},$ we can not recover $\left. \frac{dQ}{dP} \right|_{\mathscr{F}}$ from the martingale $\rho.$

**My question:**
I don't understand the remark. Why can't we get Q equivalent to P with respect to the "richer" $\mathscr{F}$? Why the "best" we can do is to obtain $ \left. \frac{dQ}{dP} \right|_{\mathscr{F}_{\infty}}$?

We know that $\rho_{\infty} \in L^1(\Omega, \mathscr{F}_{\infty}, P)$ but I think it is also true that $\rho_{\infty} \in L^1(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P).$ Hence,  I could have defined $Q(A) = \int_A \rho_{\infty} dP \quad \text{for every } A \in \mathscr{F},$ and then we would have $Q \ll P$ with respect $\mathscr{F}.$ Also, since $\rho$ is an a.s. strictly positive UI martingale, we have $P \ll Q.$ Is there anything wrong with this argument?

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Measurability w.r.t. a smaller sigma algebra implies measurability w.r.t. a larger one. So measurability  is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define 
$$Q(A) = \int_A \rho_{\infty} dP \quad \text{for all } A \in \mathscr{F},$$
then $\rho_{\infty}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of Q with respect to P on $\mathscr{F}.$ Since $\rho_{\infty}$ is $\mathscr{F}$-measurable,
$$E[\rho_{\infty} | \mathscr{F}] = \rho_{\infty}.$$
But if $\mathscr{F}$ is richer than $\mathscr{F}_{\infty},$ it could happen that
$$E[\rho_{\infty} | \mathscr{F}] = \rho_{\infty} \neq E[\rho_{\infty} | \mathscr{F}_{\infty}],$$ 
so the UI martingale wouldn't be $\{ \mathscr{F}_t \}$-adapted, which would be a contradiction. Thus, we are forced to define $Q$ **only** for all $A \in \mathscr{F}_{\infty}.$